# Fluent nHibernate reference by Id (not by object)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, database-migration, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class User, which is in the core module of the system:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set; }
}
```

I have also a class Company, which is in another module of the system and doesn't have a reference to the core module:

```
public class Company
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set; }
    public virtual int OwnerUserId {get; set;}
}
```

How can I create a mapping of Company.OwnerUserId to be a foreign key to User.Id in database? Again, note: this mapping cannot have a reference to "User" class.

Comment: Why you don't use `Map(x => x.OwnerUserId)`?

Comment: That won't generate foreign key, will it?

Comment: Are you using nhibernate for db migration?

Comment: In application - no. In tests I'm using nHibernate to generate whole database. Of course I can add it in migration scripts for the application or tests. However I wanted to know if there is a "native" support for this?

Comment: No. Each module sees only it's mapping. However, "User" will never be deleted (only marked as "deleted") therefore a foreign key reference is acceptable solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a workaround, im not sure how the schema update will generate the foreign key without mapping reference to get the metadata.

You can create a new entity mapped to the same table:

```
public class LocalUser
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual LocalUser OwnerUserId { get; set; }
}

public class LocalUserMap : ClassMap<LocalUser>
{
    public LocalUserMap()
    {
        Table("[User]");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a new entity mapped to the same table is a perfect workaround for me. Is there any chance to have the property "OwnerUserId" type of int, instead of string? Just to point out in model that this is the boundary and I could make the class LocalUser obsolete in that module (because it should be used anywhere despite the mapping).

Comment: I dont get it, create additional property in which class?

Comment: Not additional property. I want to have entity Company as:

    public class Company
    {
(...)
        public virtual int OwnerUserId { get; set; }
    }

and I don't mind having LocalUser (in project), but not as a property in Company.

Comment: Please join to the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101378/nhibernate-support